# Dynamically filter on a date label results as - yesterday results

Tags: date, prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm building a Grafana dashboard with data source Prometheus.

I have a json of label = DATE and numeric Value for each date. Date format is YYYY-MM-DD.

I want to filter in the metrics browser, only the labels of specific days.

Always filter on yesterday for example (not a specific date as 2023-08-01).

I tried many syntaxes but no success:

- `metric_name{date = today()}`
- `metric_name{date=~"^(.*)-2d$"}`
- `metric_name{date=~"$(time()-2d:1d)"}`

Comment: "I have a json of label = DATE" nothing of this is json. Am I correct to assume that you meant labels like `{label="value"}`? Or is it something other?

Comment: Do this date labels relate to moment of scraping in any way? And if yes, couldn't all this be replaced with some combination of `timestamp` and `time()` functions?

Comment: How this relates with dashboards time range? Should today mean day of the "to" field, or irrespective of it current date?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why do you put a date in your labels ? This would bring high cardinality, and is redundant with the concept of a timeseries database.